# Can I do CreateRemoteThread without being blocked by AV?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, assembly, code-injection

My questions is what the title says. Can I run a *remote* thread without being blocked by some antivirus applications?

ReadProcessMemory is slow, so I need to inject my own code into the process and read it's own memory.

Comment: Re: "Can I run a thread without being blocked by some antivirus applications?" - Of course. Otherwise *nothing* will run, since every process will have at least one thread running.

Comment: How is the AV supposed to guess that you are not a virus?  They have exclusion list, each their own of course.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not anti-virus software is running should not affect this. You'll need elevated rights, though, but ReadProcessMemory requires that anyway.

Comment: Avira gives a warning every time I try to CreateRemoteThread.

Comment: @Blez: Does it depend on which process you create a thread into?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No, it's automatically detected as a virus.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to ask that process somehow to load your code. If you have access to its source code, you can add an IPC interface for that. If that program has plugin/addon interface, consider writing a plugin which will contain such an interface.

On Windows, you can try `SetWindowsHookEx` API. It is more common operation than injecting a thread, so maybe AVs will ignore you this time.

Or you can ask users to add the program to AV's exclusion list.

Otherwise, there is no way to inject into a foreign process and not be suspicious. You're going to do what most malware wants to do, yet without being detected, how do you think any good AV can allow that?

Comment: I compiled my injection code with VC++ 2010 and VirusTotal showed no treat. All good, but I wonder is it good for a commercial application to do that. Can the antivirs someday detect it as a virus?